# Problem with replace var in docx document with value from bot

Tags: python, python-docx, temporary-files

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from docx import Document
import tempfile
import os
from datetime import datetime

Token = '6916931629:AAG0EB9xsAgJ5RLS_S3BErGwIhGQnr3pWJQ'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token)

previous_messages = {}
messages = []
user_data = {}
question_stack = {}  # Стек вопросов и ответов
# Вопросы для каждой переменной
questions = {
    'Name_student': 'ФИО с инициалами',
    'student_gender': 'Вы студент или студентка?',
    'student_group': 'Ваша группа:',
    'student_gender_type': 'отсутствовал' if 'студент' in 'Вы студент или студентка?' else 'отсутствовала',
    'date_lesson': 'Дата занятия',
    'prichina': 'Причина отсутствия(желательно)',
    'Date_create': datetime.now().strftime('%d %B %Y')
}

def fill_document(template_path, data):
    doc = Document(template_path)

    for key, value in data.items():
        # Replace placeholders in the document with data
        for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
            if f'{{{key}}}' in paragraph.text:
                paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(f'{{{key}}}', str(value))
                print(paragraph.text)
        for table in doc.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                for cell in row.cells:
                    if f'{{{key}}}' in cell.text:
                        cell.text = cell.text.replace(f'{{{key}}}', str(value))

    return doc

def send_document(chat_id, doc):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".docx") as temp_file:
        temp_file_name = temp_file.name
        doc.save(temp_file_name)
        temp_file.close()
        with open(temp_file_name, 'rb') as file:
            # Assume 'bot' is defined elsewhere in your code
            bot.send_document(chat_id, file)
        os.unlink(temp_file_name)  # Delete the temporary file after sending

def ask_next_question(message, user_id):
    variables = list(questions.keys())

    if user_id not in user_data:
        user_data[user_id] = {}

    current_index = len(user_data[user_id])
    variables_excluded = [var for var in variables if var not in ['student_gender_type', 'Date_create']]

    if current_index < len(variables_excluded):
        next_variable = variables_excluded[current_index]
        question_text = questions[next_variable]
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, question_text)

        # Save the question and answer in the stack
        question_stack[user_id] = {'variable': next_variable, 'question_text': question_text}
        previous_messages[message.chat.id] = [message.message_id]
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_answer)
    else:
        generate_and_send_document(message, user_id)

def process_answer(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    variable = question_stack[user_id]['variable']
    answer = message.text

    # If the variable is 'Date_create', format the date with digits only
    if variable == 'Date_create':
        answer = datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%Y')

    user_data[user_id][variable] = answer

    # Remove the question from the stack
    question_stack.pop(user_id, None)

    ask_next_question(message, user_id)

def generate_and_send_document(message, user_id):
    template_path = 'PHOTOS/College/Обьяснительная.docx'

    if user_id in user_data:
        document_data = user_data[user_id]
        filled_document = fill_document(template_path, document_data)
        send_document(message.chat.id, filled_document)
        del user_data[user_id]
def send_start_message(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гос.услуги", callback_data='goverments')
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Колледж", callback_data='college')
    item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Судебное", callback_data='courts')
    item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нотариус", callback_data='notarius')
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)
    sent_message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите образец который хотите получить", reply_markup=markup)
    # Сохраняем только текущее сообщение пользователя в списке
    previous_messages[message.chat.id] = [sent_message.message_id]


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    # Отправляем информацию о студенте
    student_info = "Данный бот является курсовым проектом студента группы
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, student_info)

    # Отправляем ссылки на инстаграм и вк
    instagram_link = "https://www.instagram.com/"
    vk_link = "https://vk.com"
    social_media_info = f"Инстаграм: {instagram_link}\nВКонтакте: {vk_link}"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, social_media_info)

    # Просим пользователя написать слово "Документы" для начала работы
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Для начала работы бота напишите слово 'Документы'")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'документы' or message.text.lower() == '/start')
def handle_start_message(message):
    send_start_message(message)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handle_callback_query(call):
    user_id = call.from_user.id
    if call.message.chat.id in previous_messages:
        for msg_id in previous_messages[call.message.chat.id]:
            bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, msg_id)
        previous_messages[call.message.chat.id] = []  # Очищаем список
    if call.data == 'college_button1':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Начнем опрос. Ответьте на следующие вопросы:")
        user_data[user_id] = {}
        ask_next_question(call.message, user_id)
    elif call.data == 'college_back_button':
        send_start_message(call.message)

    # ... (остальной ваш код)
    if call.data == 'goverments':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гос.услуги 1", callback_data='goverments_buttion1')
        item1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гос.услуги 2", callback_data='goverments_buttion2')
        item1_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Гос.услуги 3", callback_data='goverments_buttion3')
        item1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Назад", callback_data='goverments_back_button')
        markup1.add(item1_1, item1_2, item1_3, item1_4)
        sent_message = bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Выберите документ", reply_markup=markup1)
        # Сохраняем только текущее сообщение пользователя в списке
        previous_messages[call.message.chat.id] = [sent_message.message_id]
    elif call.data == 'goverments_back_button':
        send_start_message(call.message)
    if call.data == 'college':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item2_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Обьяснительная", callback_data='college_button1')
        item2_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Заявления", callback_data='college_button2')
        item2_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Просьба", callback_data='college_button3')
        item2_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Назад", callback_data='college_back_button')
        markup1.add(item2_1, item2_2, item2_3, item2_4)
        sent_message = bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Выберите документ", reply_markup=markup1)
        previous_messages[call.message.chat.id] = [sent_message.message_id]
    elif call.data == 'college_back_button':
        send_start_message(call.message)
    if call.data == 'courts':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item3_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Признание гражданина недееспособным", callback_data='courts_button1')
        item3_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("О возмещение ущерба дтп", callback_data='courts_button2')
        item3_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Об установление факта смерти", callback_data='courts_button3')
        item3_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Назад", callback_data='courts_back_button')
        markup1.add(item3_1, item3_2, item3_3, item3_4)
        sent_message = bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Выберите документ", reply_markup=markup1)
        # Сохраняем только текущее сообщение пользователя в списке
        previous_messages[call.message.chat.id] = [sent_message.message_id]
    elif call.data == 'courts_back_button ':
        send_start_message(call.message)
    if call.data == 'notarius':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item4_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нотариальные документы 1", callback_data='notarius_button1')
        item4_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нотариальные документы 2", callback_data='notarius_button2')
        item4_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нотариальные документы 3", callback_data='notarius_button3')
        item4_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Назад", callback_data='notarius_back_button')
        markup1.add(item4_1, item4_2, item4_3, item4_4)
        sent_message = bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Выберите документ", reply_markup=markup1)
        # Сохраняем только текущее сообщение пользователя в списке
        previous_messages[call.message.chat.id] = [sent_message.message_id]


# Эта строка запускает бота и начинает прослушивание сообщений
bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=123)
```

Document:

```
Я { student_gender } группы { student_group }  { Name_student } , { student_gender_type } на занятие { date_lesson } , { prichina }.
                                                                    {Date_create}
                    __________________
```

How can I fix them? Values doesn't insert in document.
Now the ask a variables for insert, saving them values, but doesn't insert them in document sample. The created document remains the same as the template without changes.